# Retrieving maker notes from BitmapMetadata of JPEG file using Metadata query lanaguage

Tags: c#, .net, metadata

How do you retrieve the maker notes from an image using Metadata query language? The image I'm trying with is a jpeg taken with a Nikon D300s.

I've been able to get the EXIF and GPS data OK but I'm unsure which IFD and query string to use to find the maker notes.

I tried a variety of different IFDs (Nikon, Nikon3, Nikon-3 etc) and queries but could not retrieve any results:

```
tagValueQuery = string.Format("/app1/ifd/Nikon3/subifd:{{ushort={0}}}", tag);
            if (metadata.ContainsQuery(tagValueQuery))
                return metadata.GetQuery(tagValueQuery);
```

I've been using this website as a reference for the Nikon tag numbers: http://gvsoft.homedns.org/exif/makernote-nikon-type3.html.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To get EXIF values for standard camera tags (FNumber, ExposureTime, etc.) I used the list defined on the MSDN - Native Image Format Metadata Queries (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719904%28VS.85%29.aspx) - scroll down and under EXIF Metadata you can get the names of the tags.

To get the value of the tag, you need to add "System.Photo." before tag name. For example to get the FNumber the full tag name is: "System.Photo.FNumber".

I have written the following helper methods to read EXIF data:

```
public object GetMetadataValue(BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata, string metadataQuery)
{
    object metadataValue;

    metadataQuery = "System.Photo." + metadataQuery;

    if (bitmapMetadata.ContainsQuery(metadataQuery))
        metadataValue = bitmapMetadata.GetQuery(metadataQuery);
    else
        metadataValue = null;

    return metadataValue;
}

public T GetMetadataValue<T>(BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata, string metadataQuery)
{
    object metadataValue = GetMetadataValue(bitmapMetadata, metadataQuery);

    if (metadataValue != null && metadataValue.GetType() == typeof(T))
        return (T)metadataValue;

    return default(T);
}

public string GetMetadataText(BitmapMetadata bitmapMetadata, string metadataQuery)
{
    object metadataValue = GetMetadataValue(bitmapMetadata, metadataQuery);

    return metadataValue == null ? "" : metadataValue.ToString();
}
```

Than FNumber can be simply get with:

```
GetMetadataText(bitmapMetadate, "FNumber")
```

Getting exposure time is a little bit more tricky:

```
string exposureTimeText;
double exposureTime = GetMetadataValue<double>(bitmapMetadate, "ExposureTime");

if (exposureTime == 0.0)
    exposureTimeText = "";
else if (exposureTime < 1.0)
    exposureTimeText = string.Format("1/{0}s", 1 / exposureTime);
else
    exposureTimeText = string.Format("{0:0.0}s", exposureTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have no problem getting the standard EXIF data, but I've been unable to retrieve manufacturer specific data (maker notes) which isn't in any of the MSDN or EXIF specifications.